# Non-static method cannot be referenced from static context, but nothing is static

Tags: java

I've looked at other answers on this subject and didn't find anything to help. Here are the classes I have:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
* Manage the stock in a business.
* The stock is described by zero or more Products.
* 
* @author  
* @version
*/
public class StockManager
{
// A list of the products.
private ArrayList<Product> stock;

/**
 * Initialise the stock manager.
 */
public StockManager()
{
    stock = new ArrayList<Product>();
}

/**
 * Add a product to the list.
 * @param item The item to be added.
 */

public void addProduct(Product item)
{

    for(Product product: stock)
    {
        if(Product.getID() == item)
        {
            System.out.println("Please add an item with a different id");
        }

        else
        {
         stock.add(item);

        }
    }
}

/**
 * Receive a delivery of a particular product.
 * Increase the quantity of the product by the given amount.
 * @param id The ID of the product.
 * @param amount The amount to increase the quantity by.
 */

public void delivery(int id, int amount)
{
   for(Product product : stock)
   {
       if(findProduct(id) != null)
       {
            increaseQuantity(amount);

        }

   }
}

/**
 * Try to find a product in the stock with the given id.
 * @return The identified product, or null if there is none
 *         with a matching ID.
 */

public Product findProduct(int id)
{
    for(Product product : stock)
    {
       if( id == getID())
       {
         return getName();  
       }

       else
       {
           return null;
       }



    }
}

/**
 * Locate a product with the given ID, and return how
 * many of this item are in stock. If the ID does not
 * match any product, return zero.
 * @param id The ID of the product.
 * @return The quantity of the given product in stock.
 */
public int numberInStock(int id)
{
    for(Product product : stock)
    {
        if(id == getID())
        {
            getQuantity();
        }

        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }


}

/**
 * Print details of all the products.
 */
public void printProductDetails()
{
    for( Product product: stock)
    {
       toString();
    }
}


/**
 * This method prints the deatils
 * of products under a certain quantity
 * @param the amount you want to check under
 */
public void lowStockCheck(int amount)
{
    for(Product product : stock)
    {
        if( getQuantity() < amount)
        {
            printProductDetails();
        }
    }

}

/**
 * Find a product via it's name
 * rather than ID
 * @param Name of product
 */
public Product findProductName(String name)
{
    for(Product product : stock)
    {
        if(name.equals(getName()))
        {
            return getName();
        }
        else
        {
          return null;  
        }

    }
}
```

And here is the Product class:

```
/**
* Model some details of a product sold by a company.
* 
* @author David J. Barnes and Michael Kölling.
* @version 2011.07.31
*/
public class Product
{
  // An identifying number for this product.
  private int id;
  // The name of this product.
  private String name;
  // The quantity of this product in stock.
  private int quantity;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Product.
 * The initial stock quantity is zero.
 * @param id The product's identifying number.
 * @param name The product's name.
 */
public Product(int id, String name)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    quantity = 0;
}

/**
 * @return The product's id.
 */
public int getID()
{
    return id;
}

/**
 * @return The product's name.
 */
public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

/**
 * @return The quantity in stock.
 */
public int getQuantity()
{
    return quantity;
}

/**
 * @return The id, name and quantity in stock.
 */
public String toString()
{
    return id + ": " +
           name +
           " stock level: " + quantity;
}

/**
 * Restock with the given amount of this product.
 * The current quantity is incremented by the given amount.
 * @param amount The number of new items added to the stock.
 *               This must be greater than zero.
 */
public void increaseQuantity(int amount)
{
    if(amount > 0) {
        quantity += amount;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Attempt to restock " +
                           name +
                           " with a non-positive amount: " +
                           amount);
    }
}

/**
 * Sell one of these products.
 * An error is reported if there appears to be no stock.
 */
public void sellOne()
{
    if(quantity > 0) {
        quantity--;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(
            "Attempt to sell an out of stock item: " + name);
    }
}
```

The error I get is in the addProduct function in the StockManager class. This piece of code specifically

```
/**
 * Add a product to the list.
 * @param item The item to be added.
 */

 public void addProduct(Product item)
{

    for(Product product: stock)
    {
        if(Product.getID() == item)
        {
            System.out.println("Please add an item with a different id");
        }

        else
        {
         stock.add(item);

        }
    }
}
```

The error says "non-static method getID() cannot be referenced from a static context" Neither of these methods are static, as at this point in time we have no need for them. What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you mean `product.getID()`, with a _lowercase_ `p`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please always try to reduce your problem to a [mcve] - you've included over 250 lines of code here, for something that could have been shown in about 15.

Comment: Oh my God.. I've been trying to fix this for like three days now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling Product.getID(). Product is the class name and the only methods you can invoke in such a way are static class methods.
In your case getID() is not a static method and therefore should be called by an instance of the class. Product is not an instance of Product, the p should be lowercase in reference to the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
if(Product.getID() == item)
```

with:

```
if(product.getID() == item)
```

`Product` (with uppercase P) is the classname while `product` is the instance name.

Answer (score 0):

getID method is an instance method. It means you will have to create an object for it in order to use it and to access the data fields of this class so that it can return ID of an OBJECT that is created.

> You are actually accessing the method by calling the class name like you call an static method. But it won't call it by `class.methodName();`
>   Try calling it directly.